# ERROR in node_modules/raven-js/typescript/raven.d.ts(205,11): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'

Tags: angular6, typescript2.0, sentry

I am getting this error while I am doing `ng build` in angular project. [image: Error Image]

Please find the **package.json** file here.

```
{
  "name": "web-user",
  "version": "6.0.0",
  "license": "Apache",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-prod": "ng build --prod",
    "build-stag": "ng build --stag",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test-ci": "TEST_CI=true ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "use": "firebase use PROJECTID --token FIREBASE_TOKEN",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only hosting:web-user --token FIREBASE_TOKEN --non-interactive",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "~1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/animations": "~6.0.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "~6.3.1",
    "@angular/common": "~6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~6.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~6.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "~6.3.1",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~6.0.0",
    "@firebase/firestore-types": "^0.7.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.2.2",
    "@ngu/carousel": "^1.5.5",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^2.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "~10.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "~3.0.1",
    "@types/algoliasearch": "^3.27.8",
    "@types/uuid": "~3.4.3",
    "algoliasearch": "^3.30.0",
    "amazing-time-picker": "^1.5.3",
    "angular-custom-dropdown": "^1.1.1",
    "angular-google-gapi": "^1.0.1",
    "angular-inport": "^2.0.1",
    "angular2-draggable": "^2.2.1",
    "bodymovin": "^4.13.0",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.7",
    "core-js": "~2.5.5",
    "firebase": "^5.5.3",
    "firebase-tools": "4.2.1",
    "firestore": "^1.1.6",
    "font-awesome": "~4.7.0",
    "geofirestore": "file:geofirestore-master",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.1",
    "hammerjs": "~2.0.8",
    "jquery": "~3.3.1",
    "lottie-web": "^5.4.4",
    "material-design-iconic-font": "~2.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ng-click-outside": "^4.0.0",
    "ng-gapi": "0.0.7",
    "ng-lottie": "^0.3.2",
    "ng-otp-input": "^1.3.3",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^6.0.16",
    "ng2-img-cropper": "^0.9.0",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.7.13",
    "ng2-search-filter": "~0.4.7",
    "ng4-loading-spinner": "^1.2.3",
    "ngx-accordion": "0.0.17",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.1.4",
    "ngx-facebook": "^2.4.0",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^1.3.8",
    "ngx-img-cropper": "^0.11.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^6.0.1",
    "ngx-international-phone-number": "^0.1.3",
    "ngx-lazy-load-images": "^1.3.1",
    "ngx-mask": "~6.0.1",
    "ngx-owl-carousel": "^2.0.7",
    "ngx-stripe": "^0.8.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^8.8.0",
    "nouislider": "~11.1.0",
    "owl.carousel": "^2.3.4",
    "raven-js": "^3.27.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "~6.2.1",
    "twitter": "^1.7.1",
    "twitter-js-client": "0.0.5",
    "xlsx": "^0.13.5",
    "yarn": "~1.6.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~6.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~6.0.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "~3.30.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~9.6.1",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.0.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: `unknown` is a typescript 3+ type